# How to encode Email if it contains "+" to %2B in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, urlencode

How to encode URL parameters with UTF8 encoding:
URL?email=test+@gmail.com to URL?email=test%2B@gmail.com

I tried 'test+@gmail.com'.encode("UTF-8")

CGI::escape('test+@gmail.com') it returns 'test%2B%40gmail.com But i need test%2B@gmail.com

email=test+@gmail.com should encode to "+"only rest remain same
URL?email=test%2B@gmail.com

Comment: You probably should be wondering yourself why you'd like to pass a e-mail in the URL params... this is commonly bad practice.

Comment: Why do you want to encode the `+` in the URL but not the `@`? `@` must be encoded too.

Comment: yes I know it should be encoded, but this requirement is this only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `uri` std-lib has a method for that [`URI::Escape#escape`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Escape.html#method-i-escape). `URI` extends the `URI::Escape` module, so also has this method.

```
URI.escape('test+@gmail.com', '+')
#=> "test%2B@gmail.com"        ^ the characters to escape with URL encoding
```

However like [@spickermann says in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56218696/how-to-encode-email-if-it-contains-to-2b-in-ruby#comment99061110_56218696):

> Why do you want to encode the `+` in the URL but not the `@`? `@` must be encoded too.

Comment: I've had to do this when building params for an OAuth (v1) API.  So the answer is "to fit other people's dumb expectations".  I didn't know about this way of using `URI.escape` with the extra argument though, that's handy.

Comment: Keep in mind that the answer is currently **only escaping the `+` character**, and no other characters. If you want to escape other characters like `?`, `%`, etc you'll have to include them in the second argument as well.

Comment: Ah, so the inconsistency with space is kind of part of the system then.  thanks